# How can I listen to changes of multiple providers from a future builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to display a BarChart where I use as source information two different providers.

My initial approach was to use a future builder where I show a loading icon while the data is being fetched, and then manipulate that data to suite my needs in the graph.

So I used a future builder from the widget where I display my graph and initialized it with a `Future` that will get the context from another reusable file.

`my_wdiget.dart`

```dart
...
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late Future<List<MyObject>> myFutureVariable;

 Future<List<MyObject>> _getMyObjects() async {
    return getMyObjects(context);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFutureVariable= _getMyObjects();
  }

...


FutureBuilder<List<MyObject>>(
                future: myFutureVariable,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<MyObject>> snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
                  
                      );
                    default:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Center(
                                    child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'))),

                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                        return Center(
                                    child:
                                        Text('You don\'t have any item yet.'))),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return BarChart(
                            _getChartData(snapshot.data!),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                  }
                },
              ),
```

And this is the file where I generate the data:

`my_object_utils.dart`

```dart
Future<List<MyObject>> getMyObjects(BuildContext context) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)); // Simulation delayed query
  var source1= Provider.of<MySource1>(context, listen: false).items;
  var source2 = Provider.of<MySource2>(context, listen: false).otherItems;
  List<MyObject> myObjects= [];
  // Do some stuff to fill the myObjects using source1 and source2
  return myObjects;  
}
```

Problems:

1. This kind of works but I get the warning `use_build_context_synchronously` from the lines of the Provider.
2. I want to listen to changes, but if I set the default `listen: true` it will crash telling me to change that property.

So my question is, how can I have a `FutureBuilder` listening to changes of multiple providers?

**Update using approach suggested @hydra**:
If I have:

```dart
  void test() {
    print('a');
    setState(() {});
  }

Consumer2<MySource1, MySource1>(
  builder: (context, sourceOne, sourceTwo, child) {
    myFutureVariable = getMyObjects(sourceOne.items, sourceTwo.otherItems),
    return FutureBuilder<List<MyObject>>(
      future: myFutureVariable,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          ... 
           else{
             return child: ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text('a'),
                                onPressed: test,
                              );
      }
      }
    ),
  },
),
```

Every time the button is pressed it will trigger the `setState` and and the `circularProgressIndicator` will appear although no changes were made in the consumers.

Answer (score 0):

to solve both problems you can use [Consumer2](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer2-class.html)

the `FutureBuilder` will rebuild if either of the two provider changed

```
Consumer2<MySource1, MySource1>(
  builder: (context, sourceOne, sourceTwo, child) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<MyObject>>(
      future: myFutureVariable(sourceOne.items, sourceTwo.otherItems),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // ...
      }
    ),
  },
),
```

and update your function to:

```
Future<List<MyObject>> getMyObjects(final items, final otherItems) async {
  // use your items and otherItems here.
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)); // just for testing, right?
  List<MyObject> myObjects= [];
  // Do some stuff to fill the myObjects using source1 and source2
  return myObjects;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that I was looking for. But I have a problem with that solution, you wrote `future: myFutureVariable(sourceOne.items, sourceTwo.otherItems),` but that is rebuilt everytime setState is called, causing `setState() called after dispose()` in elements under the futureBuilder`

Comment: I have no idea, can you add a snippet of code of where you use `setState()`

Comment: I have updated my question to add this information.